# JMeter web login test returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use JMeter to load test a web login form running on a local VM, but I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized response.  I setup a JMeter proxy to record the steps then added the HTTP Cookie Manager but it still will not authenticate.

[image: HTTP Request]

[image: Request Redirect]

[image: Request 2nd Redirect]

[image: This page should be the user's profile page after successful login]

The Cookie Manager gets used and adds the _auth_session to the request but the login still fails.  The initial request is a POST method passing the username/password info.  I can't seem to figure out why it's not actually authenticating.  When I record the steps it works fine but playback fails.  This appears to be a headless browser issue because recording the same steps in Selenium IDE plays it back perfectly and there is no 401 response.  Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Running Windows 7/64

Comment: Show your samplers configuration

Comment: I will suggest you to use latest version of Jmeter i.e. 4.0 in which concept of workbench is eliminated and everything is under Test plan now.Solution of above mentioned problem is to add HTTP Cookie Manager with default values.
For reference :
https://totallytechycom.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/how-to-deal-with-401-unauthorized-in-jmeter-4-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problems, so if anyone else experiences the same hardships please check this site out.

http://ertw.com/blog/2010/06/29/load-testing-a-rails-app-and-the-authenticity_token/

The problem I was having is authenticating against a Rails web app that had a hidden authenticity_token element.  A regular expression is needed to extract the dynamic value and then include it in the form post in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to tell you whats wrong without looking at the scripts. So i will just guess and give you couple of pointers.

1. You might want to keep the cookie manager above the rest of block. That is just below the Thread controller (*i.e. thread group level*). This might not be the problem as I can see the _auth_session cookie in your failing step, but still that is a good practice.
2. If you think this could be because of browser not identified by the server, You can use header manager and send browser (user_agent) information through it. see [**example**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#header_manager_example)
3. Try fiddling with the Cookie Policy and Implementation options in cookie manager.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I actually had a Header Manager in there as a child to the HTTP Request because it was recorded through the JMeter proxy.  It contains the content-type, user-agent, etc.  I moved the Header Manager and the Cookie Manager to the top of the Thread Group as you suggested but I'm still having the same issue.  I also tried different combinations of the Cookie Policy/Implementation.  Setting this up seems relatively straight forward, so I don't understand why I'm having these problems.  I have read a lot of advice and even tried the Authorization Manager, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try matching the response with one in net panel of firebug... may be that will help ... else I wont be of much help without the script. (and I know I am telling you the things that you already know, but sometime a third eye helps)

Comment: I tried adding other cookie values that I saw in firebug but it's still not helping.  Thank you for taking the time to look into this with me.  I would like to use JMeter but at this point I might have to try other tools and see how far I can get.